# Adding labels to the default Golang Prometheus metrics

Tags: http, go, prometheus

I am currently using `github.com/prometheus/client_golang` to serve as an endpoint for retrieving metrics for my Golang appplication. It provides many default datasets out of the box, for example:

```
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 0
go_gc_duration_seconds_count 0
# HELP go_goroutines Number of goroutines that currently exist.
# TYPE go_goroutines gauge
go_goroutines 10
# HELP go_info Information about the Go environment.
# TYPE go_info gauge
go_info{version="go1.13.10"} 1
```

It seems like I can not find any functionality in the library to add labels to these datasets. Because I'll have many of these applications running on the same machine, I need to add labels to differentiate the datapoints. Is there any way to do this in the `client_golang` library?

Answer (score 2):

You need a custom registry that knows how to add custom labels to metrics :)

```golang
type customMetricsRegistry struct {
    *prometheus.Registry
    customLabels []*io_prometheus_client.LabelPair
}

func NewCustomMetricsRegistry(labels map[string]string) *customMetricsRegistry {
    c := &customMetricsRegistry{
        Registry: prometheus.NewRegistry(),
    }

    for k, v := range labels {
        c.customLabels = append(c.customLabels, &io_prometheus_client.LabelPair{
            Name:  &k,
            Value: &v,
        })
    }

    return c
}

func (g *customMetricsRegistry) Gather() ([]*io_prometheus_client.MetricFamily, error) {
    metricFamilies, err := g.Registry.Gather()

    for _, metricFamily := range metricFamilies {
        metrics := metricFamily.Metric
        for _, metric := range metrics {
            metric.Label = append(metric.Label, g.customLabels...)
        }
    }

    return metricFamilies, err
}
```

and then use it like so:

```golang
metricsRegistry := NewCustomMetricsRegistry(map[string]string{"hello": "world"})
metricsRegistry.MustRegister(collectors.NewGoCollector())
```

Answer (score 1):

Each one of those applications should be scraped by prometheus as a separate job/instance. It will add the `job` label and an `instance` label which can also differentiate the different processes (and allow you to differentiate multiple instances of the same job).

See https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/#automatically-generated-labels-and-time-series for further details.

You could also use relabelling rules to add additional labels, depending on how you discover the applications. If you are using a static config (https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#static_config), you can add extra differentiating labels in that config. Similarly for `file_sd_config`: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config

Answer (score -1):

There's an option to add constant labels. E.G:

```
var (
    labels = map[string]string{"application": "foobar"}

    // Status Metrics
    StateCalls = prometheus.NewCounter(prometheus.CounterOpts{
        Name:        "state_calls",
        Help:        "",
        ConstLabels: labels,
    })
)
```

Comment: You are creating a new metric, but OP is asking how to modify an existing metric